# Job view scrolling bug with the floating "apply now" bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was looking at the job at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/134363/senior-android-mobile-developer-powering-the-iot-purepoint) page.

Once I've started to scroll the page down it starts to blink as crazy. I've recorded a video.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Ni4b7GnVO_S0JtRVB2SnVrUzg

**A [Duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343182/floating-apply-now-bar-gets-stuck-on-jobs) was posted with these details:**

I'm using Chrome latest on Windows 10.

I clicked through to a [job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/132741/6-billion-and-70k-customers-desperately-octopus-investments) and scrolled around a little and the floating nav for "apply now" just got stuck and started yo-yo-ing and the content jumps up and down.

**Example:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Reproducution steps:**

If you scroll to the point around where the bar drops in, the visibility control is *sometimes* spammed with hide/show requests and the bar will show/hide numerous times until the spammed commands have all been handled.

I can recreate consistently on [other jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/127837/senior-c-plus-plus-developer-banking-financial-or-essential-algorithms-solutions), but no all. I'm not sure if there is something related to the HTML content of the post that is causing this?

Can't reproduce this on Firefox latest or MS Edge. I have browser plugins, but disabled all after seeing this to see if they were the cause, but it continued to happen.

Comment: Here is a reproduction video https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Ni4b7GnVO_SDhFWDIzZElXSmM

Comment: There is something weird going on indeed. Only happens on Chrome, I can't repro on Edge or FF (all Win 10)

Comment: Thanks, looking into it now

Comment: Fix for this is now waiting in repo for build. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
There were some weird things happening in JS which were causing this issue. It now should be fixed on production.

Thanks again for reporting.