# Floating "apply now" bar gets stuck on Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm using Chrome latest Windows 10.

I clicked through to a [job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/132741/6-billion-and-70k-customers-desperately-octopus-investments) and scrolled around a little and the floating nav for "apply now" just got stuck and started yo-yo-ing and the content jumps up and down.

**Example:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Reproducution steps:**

If you scroll to the point around where the bar drops in, the visibility control is *sometimes* spammed with hide/show requests and the bar will show/hide numerous times until the spammed commands have all been handled.

I can recreate consistently on [other jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/127837/senior-c-plus-plus-developer-banking-financial-or-essential-algorithms-solutions), but no all. I'm not sure if there is something related to the HTML content of the post that is causing this?

Can't reproduce this on Firefox latest or MS Edge. I have browser plugins, but disabled all after seeing this to see if they were the cause, but it continued to happen.

Comment: @DeanWard thanks, I did search but didn't find that dupe.

Comment: no big deal; I only knew about it 'cos I marked the other one as `status-reproduced` earlier today ;)

Comment: Tanner, you might want to edit your image into the other question. As much as I dislike animated GIFs, they are *way* better than a video linked offsite. This bug report makes a lot more sense to me than the other one.

Comment: @CodyGray will do when I get to the office

Comment: @CodyGray would it be bad to replace all of the content in the other bug report with mine and delete my question if this is clearer?

Comment: I don't think a major edit is bad. Whatever you think is most clear and useful. You might strike a balance by keeping the link to the video at the bottom.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks, I have made the edit. It would seem in cases like this where 2 similar questions were posted in a short space of time, it would be useful to switch it around, so that the more detailed post could be made the main question and the other one the child. I guess that's never really been done before though and would open up other issues. _just thinking out loud_.

Comment: Duplicate closure can happen in any direction. Dean just picked this one to close as a duplicate for no reason other than the other one was first and he'd already tagged it [status-reproduced]. Normally, you *would* use the better question as the master.