# New topbar nav: bug when browsing jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, google-chrome

1. Go to Stack Overflow
2. Go to Jobs
3. Browse one job opening
4. Scroll down enough so the "Jobs" header takes over the regular (new) top bar
5. Scroll up again

Observe up/down perpetual competition between the two bars.

Comment: I've seen this myself but have not managed to reliably reproduce it.

Comment: Are you also really good at finding hidden cheat codes in video games? Nice grab :)

Comment: i raised [this the other day](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343182/floating-apply-now-bar-gets-stuck-on-jobs) but found it was a duplicate of the above question, and the team are aware of it as you can see.

Comment: I am told this was not introduced with the new header, but is something that happens with the black top bar too.