# Submitting CV breaks JavaScript

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm running into an issue with Stack Overflow Jobs:

When submitting a job application, I got a jQuery error. I did not preserve my Chrome debugging tools logs, but I figured I should include it regardless. I don't want to apply unnecessary to test this theory.

It looks like it was a Stack Overflow application that went through SO's internal messaging system for applying for a job, the UI doesn't do a good job at displaying it if it did, but I think it failed to attach my CV. (That's kind of awkward, I cannot reply to the message to correct this issue or verify with them to be extra sure, so it's possible the employer does not see my CV. Oops!)

I'm not confident what's being targeted, but if it's any help - the post ended up using Stack Overflow's [messaging system](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox), which might be part of the issue for failing to attach a CV, as it doesn't look like it supports attachments to begin with.

This is all theoretical, though. I'm not sure where or what went wrong, and I'd need to find a job I want to apply on before I can attempt reproducing it.

From memory, this is roughly what I did, in case anyone can reproduce it:

- Visit https://stackoverflow.com/jobs
- Select a job you fancy

  - Whether this matters I don't know - but it has to at least use StackOverflow for applying, and not redirect to their recruitment page.
  - StackOverflow staff is free to request the specific page it happened on in private, if they can't look it up themselves
- Click on "Apply", fill in the fields, leave CV blank to have StackOverflow upload your Developer Story in PDF format.
- Click "Submit" in the popup menu, an error should appear in your developer console.

  - Your application will still be submitted, and can be viewed in StackOverflow's [messaging system](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox)
  - Not part of the bug, but it will be ambiguous whether your CV was attached, the UI does not indicate this, but in the comments section of this post someone explains that it *was* attached.

I'm running the following chrome extensions:

AdBlock 3.8.6,
Alt CSS 0.9.4.3,
BetterTTV 6.9,
Chrome Regex Search 1.0.7,
Enhanced Steam 9.2,
Google Dictionary (by Google) 4.0.5,
Google Mail Checker 4.4.0,
I don't care about cookies 2.6.5,
JSON Viewer 0.17.0,
LastPass: Free Password Manager 4.1.40,
Magic Actions for YouTube™ 6.9.3.0,
Reddit Enhancement Suite 5.4.2,
RSS Subscription Extension (by Google) 2.2.4,
Stylish - Custom themes for any website 1.7.2,
Turn Off the Lights 3.3.0.21,
uBlock Origin 1.11.0

No proxies/VPNs were in use.

Comment: You can remove point 1, or reference [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343069/job-view-scrolling-bug-with-the-floating-apply-now-bar) as it's a duplicate. I've not close voted as you make 2 points here, please edit appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a hard time searching for it as I wasn't quite sure how to phrase it.

Comment: To be honest, it's probably better to remove that first point altogether and change the title to refer to your second point. They are 2 separate issues and the first has already been recorded.

Comment: I've mixed feelings about that, it might've been better to have them separated from the start (I just didn't because there's not much to go on in issue 2, but thought the logs on SO might have more), there's already some history to the issue and it might be confusing for the reader. I'll make some further edits, though

Comment: Oops, should have read the comments first :). Feel free to rollback. I really hate seeing struck-through text except in a diff view. I can't read it, and if it's irrelevant enough to strike through, it's irrelevant enough to delete. We keep a history of edit revisions, so if anyone *really* needs to know what it used to say, they can find it.

Comment: Nope - it's okay. If multiple people think removing it is the best option, I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: I'm checking this out for you, verifying if the CV got attached or not. Are you using an ads blocker? also, do you remember if you saw the full-page apply form or the pop up version? thanks!

Comment: I've been able to verify that your CV hasn't been attached. A pdf version of your developer story was used instead. If you want, send me your CV via email and I'll make sure it gets attached to your application. Regarding this issue, please make sure you save your console errors if you see this again. If you remember, please also let me know if you saw the full-page apply form or the pop up one.

Comment: Hey @g3rv4, sorry, perhaps I should have been more explicit: I did not upload a manual CV, I wanted the developers story to be attached. if it was attached, the error raised is possibly related to something else, and because the UI itself does not indicate whether your CV(/developer story) was attached or allow you to review it at any point yourself - it looked like that might've been where it went wrong. I can't remember what exactly I saw, but it broke when hitting "submit" on [this page](https://i.imgur.com/QvB4UhY.png), adblocker (uBlock and Adblock) is being used.

Comment: Alrighty, then it looks like your application was successfully submitted. We are aware that our "messages" implementation isn't good enough to track your application status, and we're thinking about ways to improve it. The tricky part is that some employers use external ATSs, but we're actively planning to improve it. I'll try to replicate your issue, but if you see another job you want to apply for (I hope you don't because you've nailed this interview and they've made you a kick ass offer by now), try to keep an eye on the console so that we have more data ;)

Comment: I've edited my original post to add reproduction steps to the best of my memory, unfortunately it's happened a while ago and I didn't pay too much attention, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Kewl, please also add the adblockers that were in use... they're 49.95% of the times the cause of these issues (the other 49.95% of the times are the CORS headers being stripped by a proxy)

Comment: If it's possible to set up some sort of testing job I could mess around with, I might be able to be of more use.  - For now, I've edited the OP to include all extensions (although the evildoers are possibly limited to AdBlock, uBlock, and perhaps I don't care about cookies) - also elaborated on (the lack of) VPN usage. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your report. We had a file conveniently named `google.analytics.so.js` that actually took care of not breaking if Google Analytics wasn't loaded.

Unfortunately, uBlock Origin was blocking it based on the filename, so our logic to handle an non-existent Google Analytics object couldn't kick in. I was able to verify that with a simple rename things went back to normal.

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this. I haven't submitted any applications in a while but I'll make sure to check in if I run into further issues in the future. I've also marked your answer as accepted.